# Android development without using Eclipse

Tags: android, emacs, ide

Ok so I am an avid user of Emacs and tend to stay away from using IDE's unless I absolutely have to and I see that it is recommended to use Eclipse with a plugin for developing android. I was just wondering if it is really necessary to use the Eclipse plugin (or some others out there)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can absolutely use Emacs: http://riddell.us/AndroidWithEmacsOnUbuntu.html. (This site has disappeared but a copy was captured by the Wayback Machine which can be found here http://web.archive.org/web/20120321225744/http://riddell.us/AndroidWithEmacsOnUbuntu.html) It describes how to use Emacs and only Emacs for a test application.
No Eclipse.

Comment: added a link from the wayback machine

Answer (score 7):

Why then not to use Eclipse with [Emacs+ plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/emacs) which will give all the power of Google tools + familiar Emacs shortcuts, etc? Alternatively you can simply set your key scheme to Emacs by doing `Eclipse->Window->Preferences->General->Keys` and setting schema to Emacs

If you are adamant on using Emacs "as is" I would also recommend looking into "Mavenizing" your project with [maven-android-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) which you can trigger from Emacs

Comment: I think the power of emacs doesn't come from the default keybindings for editing text but from the ability to modify pretty much everything according to you wishes.
Vanilla Vim defaults keybindings are way faster for editing text

Comment: I found getting around the bloatware on Eclipse irritating--there are reasons why some of us use Emacs. With the horrendous list of this-won't-work-with-that-ADT-version-and-on-this-OS business I have seen so often with Eclipse, I am just tired, and want to go back to where I feel in better control of my environment. No offense to Eclipse users, but it just does not cut it for me. My latest was "Maven Android plugin won't work with Eclipse 3.8.1 installed by Ubuntu 14.04--" no, I don't have anything special in my environment. "Why not Eclipse" sounds just empty promise to me.

Answer (score 7):

I recently wrote some code to allow the use of CEDET with Android projects.  This is currently in a bzr development branch of CEDET on sourceforge.  The post is here:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27126953

It supports creating a new android project, builds, starting up the debugger, installing on a device and moving between some XML files and some matching .java files, and vs-versa.  It includes some fixes to the java support and smart completion also.

As with most things of this nature, help getting it more robust is welcome.

Basic instructions for download are here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cedet/develop

and you'll need the android branch.

Answer (score 7):

You can try Android-emacs-toolkit.
http://code.google.com/p/android-emacs-toolkit/

Android-emacs-toolkit helps to build android development
environment on emacs. It contains a emacs major mode which help
to develop android sdk and ndk program.

It provides support for *create new avd*, *launch avd*, *create
new android project*, *build and rebuild Android sdk project*,
*build and rebuild Android ndk project*, *install and uninstall
apk*, *run executable ndk project*, *output emulator log on
emacs*.

This toolkit tested on WindowsXP/7, Ubuntu11 with android-sdk and
android-ndk-r7.

Answer (score 6):

It's certainly possible not to use Eclipse. You'll miss on some features such as better semantic help with Java than I think you can't get anywhere else, but you'll gain the ability to use your favorite editor, easier-to-debug build processes, and the possibility to work on a less powerful machine.

The Developers' Guide has a section on [developing in other IDEs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html). The SDK contains a small Emacs package to debug Android applications with GUD. There's a little information in the [Emacs Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GoogleAndroid), pointing to two interfaces to run SDK tools inside Emacs (Emacs is nice for reading `logcat` output, for instance): [RemVee](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RemVee)'s [`android-mode`](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode/blob/master/android-mode.el), and [Jonathan Arkell](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JonathanArkell)'s [EmDroid](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmDroid).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Eclipse. However if you do not wish to use Eclipse, read this article:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

Comment: Yeah I read this but from some people I know there was a lot going on that the plugin would do for them so I was just wondering if it was even worth it attempting to do so rather than just using Eclipse.

Comment: I usually code using Textmate (php/js/css) and have tried to set it up for Android. Some articles explain how to do that and there are some bundle available for Textmate. But, Eclipse gives so much for free with the Android plugin, so I found out I would rather use Eclipse for Android and Textmate for everything else.

Comment: 404 :(

Did redirect back in 2012 to http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html